# Denormalisation, ACL, and filter 'find all' in LoopBack

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, nosql

I'm new to LoopBack but I love it so far. I need to filter a find all based on user dynamic role.

For instance I have a `Project` collection with a state property. If a specific project is in `draft` state only the creator can CRUD it, and is is managed by a [dynamic role](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles#Definingandusingroles-Dynamicroles). The other users can't even view them.

Example: instance operation (`findOne`, `findById` where I have the `ctx.req.params.id`) I used `app.models.ACL.checkAccessForToken` and ACL, it works great.

But.. what to do for static operation where I don't have the id? I can't use `checkAccessForToken`..

I'm new to non-relational database and in [this nice article](https://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/09/JOINs-via-denormalization-for-NoSQL-coders-Part-1-Intro) I read about de-normalization but honestly I don't like it and I'm sure that a complete framework like LoopBack can handle this problem in a more structured way (I think that filter find all operation by authorisation is a common feature in so many project).

So.. is there any alternative/standard way in LoopBack? Thanks!

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @daniloprates honestly I don't remember which workaround I used, many years ago, loobpack had changed version, I'm no more a backend developer, maybe should delete this question?